# Accidentally uninstalled current linux image, can't get system to boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I was having trouble clearing out old linux images because my boot partition was full (couldn't do `apt autoremove`), so I was removing them manually with dpkg.  When doing that I accidentally removed my current linux image.  Now I can't boot the system.  I've tried lots of GRUB purge / reinstall ideas and none of them seem to work.

I did boot-repair which also failed, and gave me this paste link to share.  Anyone have some clues as to what I can do?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/26195007/

Comment: do you have any kernels left? from the advanced options menu in grub, you should be able to pick a kernel to boot

Comment: Please confirm that you have deleted all the kernels off your system.

Comment: I have kernels left, but GRUB won't boot any of them.   I don't get the GRUB Loader.  Just a blank screen.

Comment: I take that back, I get GRUB during boot now.  I have two kernels 103, and 87.  87 hangs during "Loading initial ramdisk...." and 103 hangs when the screen turns blank after displaying the "Loading initial ramdisk..." message.  I can boot into recovery mode for either kernel, just not normal boot.

Comment: Well, progress has been made.  I don't understand what is wrong, but I think the system is booting up without selecting a TTY (if thats the right term).  When viewing the blank screen if I press CTRL-ALT-F1 I see the log-in prompt.   So at least the system works....time for another google search :)

Answer (score -1):

what i think is there is no issue regarding kernel image but the problem is with grub as this line from the pastebin says

**grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdc1.  Check your device.map.**

and when use check /dev/sdc1

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       iso9660
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 is already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sda1 busy
```

mount: /dev/sdb1 is already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdb1 busy
mount: /dev/sdc1 is already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdc1 busy

you are using a live cd to repair the grub error which cannot be resolved sda1 is already mounted

**the safest and easiest possible solution which i know is reinstall ubuntu**

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that. I'd rather not spend a day re-configuring my server...but that may be what I have to do.

Comment: downloding the specific kernel for your ubuntu system using live installation and then placing it may be an option but that is more tedious process